# mysql update adding row instead of updating

Tags: mysql, updating

i have a shell script that issues a sql query that will replace a filename in the database with another filename. it also will replace the full path by concatenating the name of the file with the name of the directory stored in a different table. it works for me but when another user tries it on another database (identical structure but different data) it will add a new record instead of updating it. i've searched but i cant figure out why it works for me and not them. all i can think of is maybe it is a permission issue. here is the query:

```
UPDATE My.files
SET strFilename="'$NFescaped'"
WHERE strFilename="'$DFescaped'";

UPDATE My.episode
SET c18 =
  (SELECT concat (
                    (SELECT strPath
                     FROM My.path
                     WHERE path.idpath=
                         (SELECT idpath
                          FROM My.files
                          WHERE strFilename="'$NFescaped'")), "'$NFescaped'"))
WHERE c18 =
    (SELECT concat (
                      (SELECT strPath
                       FROM .path
                       WHERE path.idpath=
                           (SELECT idpath
                            FROM My.files
                            WHERE strFilename="'$NFescaped'")), "'$DFescaped'"));
```

Comment: Can you take a step back and talk about the table schema for the tables you are actually trying to update? My guess is that you might be able to greatly simplify this query using a JOIN.

Comment: You wrote `UPDATE.files` with a dot, why?

Comment: yes, i'm sure i could now that you mention it. still kind of new at this. basically the database keeps track of files. the 'files' table stores the filename. the 'path' table stores the path of the file. the 'episode' table stores the full path of the file (path+filename) using foreign keys from the others. so i have it update strFilename in the 'files' table then the full path (c18) in the 'episode' table by looking for the path and combining it with the filename. I'm sure it could be simplified but my main problem is why does this update work for me but add a new row for the other person.

Comment: @rubo77, that was a typo. i will fix it.

Comment: an UPDATE will never add a line, there has to be some more code involved

Comment: well, that is all the code involved. that's why i can't figure it out.

Comment: Still needing help on this.

Comment: The code you pasted does an update, there is no way that it could do an INSERT instead. The problem is probably in a different bit of code.

Comment: Hmmm... well what other bit of code could it be? That is the only query used. I suppose it could be be a function or stored procedure in the database but that still doesn't explain why it works on one machine and not another.